# How to notate the set of leaves of a tree (data structure)?

Tags: notation, trees, data-structure

What maths notation to give to the set of elements composing leaves of a tree structure?
Suppose the tree `T` is n-ary, I want to notate the set `{n / n in Leaves(T) }`
How to do that?